# Accept timed out exception when not set "timeout time" for accept connections

Tags: java

We are using TCP server.sometimes we get following exception

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
```

I googled it and found out that it happened when exceed timout which is setby `setSoTimeout(timeinmilli)`method. but, we didnt invoke that methode.

sample tcp server:

```
class TCPServer
    {   
        public static void main(String args[]){
            public void initializeConnectionHandler(String ip, int port) {
                try{            
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, serverSocket_backlog, InetAddress.getByName(ip));            
                    log("Waiting for client on port: " +serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                    while(true){
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        log("Just connected to "+ socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                        Runnable tcpConnectionHandler = new TCPConnectionHandler(serverSocket, socket, workerManager);
                        new Thread(tcpConnectionHandler).start();
                    }       
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    log("Exception occured while initializing ConnectionHandlers: "+e);
                    logException(e);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just increase the socket time and try it

Comment: @Kick That's an answer but not to this question ;-)

Comment: Is that a copy-paste mistake? because method `initializeConnectionHandler` in `main` method doesn't look correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this exception should only occur if you've set a timeout by calling `setSoTimeout`. Nevertheless if you go through the search results you can find occasional discussions about this effect as you've seen it, e.g. in [Tomcat](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56684) where they assumed that they found a bug in the JVM and added a workaround to keep the server running.

Another result (german language, sorry) reporting about this exception with [Jenkins](http://everflux.de/jenkins-java-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-accept-timed-out-1830/) indicates that there might be problems when IPv6 is active as well. Solution there was to set the system property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` to `true`.

I'm not a fan of the latter "solution" but concerning the workaround the Tomcat-team implemented, I suggest you do the same. At least, don't stop the whole loop in case of an exception like this.

Answer (score 1):

Internally it is calling `socketAccept` method of `TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl` class.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
```

Method is native so you can't completely find the reason but below is the native code from openjdk.

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/native/java/net/TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.c

Where you can find it is throwing mentioned exception.